# how to add list items to tuples inside list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

lets say i have a list of tuples:

`[(0, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (3, 14)]`

and a list

`[22, 24, 26, 28]`

and i want to combine these to make

`[(0, 11, 22), (1, 12, 24), (2, 13, 26), (3, 14, 28)]`

is there an easy and efficient way to do this?

what if i wanted the list to be inserted into the middle of the tuple objects like:
`[(0, 22, 11), (1, 24, 12), (2, 26, 13), (3, 28, 14)]`

Or is the best way to just split the list of tuples into two lists with the first and second elements and then zip them up again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pattern matching is the way to go:

```
>>> a
[(0, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (3, 14)]
>>> b
[22, 24, 26, 28]
>>> [(i, j, k) for ((i, j), k) in zip(a, b)]
[(0, 11, 22), (1, 12, 24), (2, 13, 26), (3, 14, 28)]
```

Inserting to different positions is trivial in this case.